Probability of sum of i.i.d. random variables being positive
Let $g,l \in (0,1)$ and $p\in [0,1]$. Let $X(k,1-p)$ be a random variable with binomial distribution with parameters $k$ and $1-p$. Let $Y(k,p)$ be a random variable with binomial distribution with parameters $k$ and $p$. It is given that $X(k,1-p)$ and $Y(k,p)$ are independent. Consider the function given by:
$$
f_k(p) =\mathbb{P}((1+g)X(k,1-p) + lY(k,p) >k).
$$
Can we say that the function $f_k(p)$ is strictly decreasing in $p$?
Numerical evidence kind of suggests that the above statement is true. However, I would like to see an analytical proof of this. Any help (with either proving/disproving the above conjecture) would be greatly appreciated.
MY ATTEMPT SO FAR: Let $X_k^p$ and $Y_k^p$ be two independent binomial random variables with parameters $k$ and $p$. For $n\in\{0,1,2,\dots,k\},$ let $\overline{m}(n) = \lceil \frac{gk+ln}{1+g}\rceil - 1,$ where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the least integer function.
The function $f_k(p)$ can be written as follows:
\begin{align*}
    f_k(p) &= \mathbb{P}\left((1+g)X_k^p - lY_k^p <gk\right)\\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^k \mathbb{P}(Y_k^p=n) \mathbb{P}\left((1+g)X_k^p <gk +ln \right)\\
    &= \sum_{n=0}^k \mathbb{P}(Y_k^p=n) \mathbb{P}\left(X_k^p \leq \overline{m}(n) \right).
\end{align*}
We have,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{d}{dp}\mathbb{P}(Y_k^p=n) &= n\binom{k}{n}p^{n-1}(1-p)^{k-n} - (k-n)\binom{k}{n}p^n(1-p)^{k-n-1}\\
    &= k\left(\mathbb{P}(Y_{k-1}^p = n-1) - \mathbb{P}(Y_{k-1}^p = n) \right)\\
    \frac{d}{dp}\mathbb{P}\left(X_k^p \leq \overline{m}(n)\right) &= \frac{d}{dp} \sum_{m\leq \overline{m}(n)}\mathbb{P}\left(X_k^p = m\right)\\
    &= k \sum_{m\leq \overline{m}(n)}\left(\mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = m-1) - \mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = m) \right)\\
    &= -\mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = \overline{m}(n)).
\end{align*}
Using the above set of equations and the chain rule, we get
\begin{align*}
    \frac{f_k'(p)}{k} &= \sum_{n=0}^k(\mathbb{P}(Y_{k-1}^p=n-1)-\mathbb{P}(Y_{k-1}^p=n))\mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p< gk+ln)\\
    & - \sum_{n=0}^k \mathbb{P}(Y_k^p = n)\mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = \overline{m}(n))\\
    &= \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p < gk+lY_{k-1}^p+l) - \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p<gk+lY_{k-1}^p)\\
    & - \mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = \overline{m}(Y_k^p)).
\end{align*}
We compute as follows,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(X_{k-1}^p = \overline{m}(Y_k^p)) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X_{k-1}^p = \left\lceil \frac{gk+lY_k^p}{1+g} \right\rceil-1\right)\\
    &= \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{gk+lY_k^p}{1+g} \leq X_{k-1}^p+1 < \frac{gk+lY_k^p}{1+g}+1\right)\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(gk-g-1 \leq (1+g)X_{k-1}^p - lY_k^p <gk).
\end{align*}
From the above series of equations it follows that $f_k'(p) \leq 0$ if and only if the following holds:
\begin{align*}
    & \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p-lY_{k-1}^p<gk+l) - \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p- lY_{k-1}^p < gk)\\
    & \leq \mathbb{P}(gk-g-1 \leq (1+g)X_{k-1}^p - lY_k^p <gk)\\
    &\iff \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p-lY_{k-1}^p \in [gk, gk+l)) \leq \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_{k-1}^p - lY_k^p \in [gk-g-1, gk)).
\end{align*}
So now the question reduces to showing that the following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}((1+g)X_k^p-lY_{k-1}^p \in [gk, gk+l)) \leq \mathbb{P}((1+g)X_{k-1}^p - lY_k^p \in [gk-g-1, gk)).
\end{equation}
It seems that the above equation holds for the given values of $g$ and $l$. However, I do not have a rigorous proof for this yet. Any help with proving this will be greatly appreciated

Let $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(k,1-p)$, $Y\sim \operatorname{Bin}(k,p)$. Let $W=k-X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(k,p)$, then
$$
f(p)=\mathbb{P}(Z>0)
$$
where
$$
Z=(1+\gamma)(k-W)+\lambda Y-k=\gamma k+\lambda Y-(1+\gamma)W
$$
where $\lambda,\gamma\in(0,1)$.
Let $U_1,\dots,U_k,V_1,\dots,V_k$ be i.i.d. $U[0,1]$; fix them. Then we can represent
$$
Y=|\{i: U_i<p\}|,\quad W=|\{j: V_j<p\}|;
$$
$$
Z(p)=\gamma k+\lambda |\{i: U_i<p\}|-(1+\gamma)|\{j: V_j<p\}|.
$$
Let us see what happends with $Z$ as we change from $p$ to $p+dp$; both $Y$ and $W$ are non-decreasing in $p$. The probability that there will be more than one increase in $Y+W$ is of order $o(dp)$. On the other hand, the probabilities that either $Y$ or $W$ increases are equally likely due to symmetry. At the same time $1+\gamma>\lambda$, so the decrease will be stronger than increase. Hence $Z(p+dp)$ is stochastically smaller than $Z(p)$, yielding the result.

I am a bit unsure about the argument. For example, if I had a function $h(p)$ defined as follows:
$$
h(p) =\mathbb{P}((1+g)X(k,1-p) + lY(k,p) >0).
$$
Then, $h(p)$ should also be strictly decreasing in $p$ following a similar argument for why $f(p)$ is decreasing in $p.$ However, $h(p)$ is not strictly decreasing because,
$$
h(p) = 1- \mathbb{P}((1+g)X(k,1-p) + lY(k,p) =0) = 1- (p(1-p))^k.
$$
Am I missing something?
